# Mapped texture not showing in viewport

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view

The texture does not show in UV editing mode, default mode or render. I have mapped the UVs and the viewport shading is set to textured mode as shown.

I tried adding a material (it was green) and the the render shows up as green.

In a different file the texture was showing and I didn't even add a material. 
How can I get the texture to show?

This is the UV editing screen
[image]
And the Default screen (I removed the material from all objects)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For cycles, once you have your object unwrapped and textured like you have in your first screenshot, you then navigate to the material tab, and click "Use Nodes"

Now under "Surface" you should have a drop down which says "Diffuse BSDF", followed by 3 options; "Color", "Rough", and "Norm". Click the little dot to the right of the "Color" widget, and choose "Image Texture":

[image: Selecting an image texture node]

In the image texture panel, click the drop down to the left of the "Open" button, and select the image that you had open in the UV editor:

[image: Selecting the image to be used]

Now if you go into the textured view (Alt+Z), you should see your texture applied to your object.